# c++ method address vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new at using vector, I need a method that return the addres of the vector, this is the semplifide code:

class:

```
#include<vector>

class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    A()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            v[i] = i;
    }

    std::vector<int> give()
    {
          return v;
    }

    ~A() {}
};
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.cpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A a;

    int *vptr = NULL;

    vptr = &a.give()[0];

    std::vector<int> b;

    return 0;
}
```

this code compile but during the execution a segmentation fault is given

Comment: Why do you need to return the address?

Comment: Why are you #including a .cpp file?

Comment: I need to implement an MPI code and I need to scatter the vector.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm a student, I don't know why I am including a .cpp file. Which is the correct file format?

Comment: @Wellen Typically .h files are used for code to be included in other files.

Comment: @MMavipc What do you mean?

Comment: @0x499602D2 indented it properly for you.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Thank you, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constructor

```
A(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        v[i] = i;
}
```

is invalid because the vector has no yet elements that you could use the subscript operator. More correctly would be to write

```
A() : v( 5 ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        v[i] = i;
}
```

As for your question then std::vector has member function data that returns the address of its internal buffer with elements.

So you could write

```
int * give(){ return v.data(); }
```

or

```
const int * give() const { return v.data(); }
```

In main you could write

```
int *vptr = a.give();
```

Comment: Even better for the constructor, `std::iota`.

Comment: @ chris I am sure he does not know yet about standard algorithms.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's true, I don't know what std::iota i.! However thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You have several big problems here.

First, in the constructor you're trying to access elements of the vector that don't yet exist:

```
A(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        v[i] = i;
}
```

`vector` isn't the same as `map` where if the element you are looking for with `operator[]` doesn't exist a new one is created.  In `vector` if you use `operator[]` with an index that doesn't exist you get Undefined Behavior, and a verly likely crash.  You should be inserting items here.  On way is `push_back`:

```
A(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    v.push_back (i);
}
```

Next, `give()` returns a `vector` **by-value**:

```
std::vector<int> give(){
    return v;
}
```

Which makes a copy of `v` and returns that copy.  Well that's technically OK, but when you call `give()` you don't assign the return value to a variable.  What ends up happening is the copy of the vector becomes a temporary object.  As soon as the so-called "full-expression" where the temporary was created is done, the temporary is destroyed.

That full-expression is this:

```
vptr = &a.give()[0];
```

So, `vptr` was assigned the address of the first element of that temporary `vector`, but as soon as the end of this expression is reached that vector is destroyed and `vptr` now points to hyperspace.  If you attempt to dereference this wild pointer, you get Undefined Behavior and a very likely segmentation fault.

To fix this, you could let `A` tell you the address of the first element of the `vector`:

```
class A
{
// [...]
public:  
  void*  give() { return v.data(); }
};
```

Comment: And if I want to return a copy of the vector v? What I have to do?

Comment: One last question, which is the smartes way to push some elements at the beggining of the vector? There isn't a push_front method?

Comment: @Wellen: Didn't we just cover that?

Comment: I want a copy and if I operate on the copy I don't want that the vector in the class changes...

Comment: Use insert. Consult the documentation.

Comment: Great. Make a copy then.

Comment: but I need a method that return the copy... I don't know how to do that, whats the type of the method? Can I do this whitout a cycle?

Comment: Re-read my answer and you'll see that this has already been covered.

Comment: And the pointer to an element of the vector? Is there a method that give me the address to the i element?